# D: Define custom version identifier for conditional compilation

Tags: d, conditional-compilation

The D [documentation](http://dlang.org/version.html#predefined-versions) talks about predefined version identifiers, but not how to define your own version. How do I do it?

Since this feature is supposed to be the D counterpart to C/C++'s `#if`/`#ifdef`, I doubt they would lock us to only the predifined versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a version to the compiler when building with the `-version=whatever` switch.